# Securely creating an hidden service

Tags: onion-services

been reading up a lot on securely creating an hidden service, what i want to do is set up two servers at different locations, and configure them, one configured for Tor and one as a Webserver providing the hidden service etc, how do i go about setting this up, i am thinking for security to only install apache server and not php to run a static webpsite minimizing attacks etc,but i am confused on how to link the two together and what exactly needs to be installed on each machine

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you don't really need two machines for this. one should be enough. as for setup example, a torified virtual machine would be good. keep the hidden service on the host (that must not be a relay, as deanonymization of hidden services run by relays is much easier), the http server on the vm.

as for software, people run all sorts of things as hidden services, it really depends on the application.

security wise it's not much different than having a public service, with the difference being that in case the hidden service is hacked, all of its requests should be continue to be location anonymous.